# Using the OAuth Access Token from django-social-auth with Google data api (calendar)

Tags: django, oauth, gdata, google-data-api, django-socialauth

I'm trying to use the OAuth Token I get from django-social-auth to access the users calendars.

So in the django-social-auth configuration I set:

```
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY = 'anonymous'
GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'anonymous'
GOOGLE_OAUTH_EXTRA_SCOPE = ['https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/']
```

When the user comes back from google, I get an entry in the database which lookes like this:

```
{u'access_token': u'oauth_token_secret=vvvv&oauth_token=xxxx'}
```

But now, when I try do something like this:

```
import gdata.calendar.client

client = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient()
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken('anonymous', 'anonymous', 'xxxx', 'vvvv', gdata.gauth.ACCESS_TOKEN)

client.GetOwnCalendarsFeed()
```

I always get:

```
gdata.client.Unauthorized: Unauthorized - Server responded with: 401
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.</TITLE>
</HEAD>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using OAuth or OAuth2?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  Driving me nuts.  I'm using OAuth and have tried with anonymous as well as registered keys.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth

def do_something_with_tokens(request):
  tokens = UserSocialAuth.get_social_auth_for_user(request.user).get().tokens
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hallelujah!  Django-social-auth returns the access token with an escaped forward slash (%2F).  Replacing that with "/" worked for me.

HTH